# How to manage transactions with the SerialPort?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, serial-port

I'm currently working on an application that communicates with an electronic device via the SerialPort.

- This communication is done in a half-duplex fashion, where the application is the master and the device is the slave. The master needs to send a message to the device, and the device needs to respond before the next message is sent.
- If the message doesn't receive a response, the application needs to resend it.
- The content of the next message is dependent on the result of the current message. i.e. each new message has an incremented sequence number, and sometimes data for the next message is taken from the reponse of the current one.
- To send messages I use an interface to System.IO.Ports.SerialPort. When messages are received a SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is fired.

What's the best way for me to manage this? Is there a pattern that I can base this on?

Comment: Are creating your own protocol or coding to a comm specification provided with the device?

Comment: Hi @tcarvin, yes and no. The company I just started with have their own protocol for communicating with these devices. I have to make it work with that protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on something similar in the past. This is the basic structure of the messaging I have used:

Application: Send Command Seq #1 -->
<-- Device: Acknowledge command, seq #1 (including any command-specific response)

If the device didn't acknowledge within 1 second, the same command would be resent, same sequence number. This "retry" sequence would happen 3 times and then it would time out, and retire the command.

The sequence number from the application side would increment by one for every command it sent that was not a retry. It would loop back to sequence number 1 after hitting 99.

The application will have to keep track of its state based on what command(s) is "in-flight" between it and the device, and what kind of response it has received. It can identify the response to a specific command by the sequence number the device puts in its acknowledgement.

To keep it simple to transition from state to state you can make it so that there is only ever one active command and don't move on until that one has been ack'ed or timed out and retired.

Answer (score 0):

Shane Wealti approach is right but I think what you might be really asking yourself, should you use threads? Even though it is a master/slave scenario, should you have a listening thread? When do you listen to the port and when do you send?

**The simplest approach - no threads**

You don't need to use threads in this scenario due to master/slave configuration, all you have is two functions.

```
SendCommand(char * bfr)
{
}

RecieveCommand(char * bfr)
{
}

SendCommand( txBfr );
RecieveData( rxBfr );
// process receive buffer, prepare new command
SendCommand( txbfr );
RecieveCommand( rxBfr );
// and so on
```

The approach is the most simple one and totally functional. However since there are no threads and say your RecieveData() times out in one second, you GUI will not be responsive in that second. Note that you are not listening to the port all the time but only when are expecting a reply.

I might edit this to add Comprehensive approach using threads later but don't have the time right now.